# Realm file is going from KB to MB

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I have a list of 50k files which I need to save it to realm.

I am saving in the following way.Before this operation realm file is 40KB. after this it is increasing to 200 MB. Can you guys suggest me a best way or what's wrong with my code. I have created a function to save the list of realm files.

```
func saveList<T: Object>(_ list: List<T>?) {
        autoreleasepool {
            if let list = list {
                let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "realm", qos: .background, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)
                var defaultRealm: Realm?
                backgroundQueue.sync {
                    autoreleasepool {
                    do {
                        defaultRealm = try Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(fileURL:URL(path)))
                    } catch let error {
                        debugPrint("Realm Can't be created on  thread \(Thread.current) and error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    if let realm = defaultRealm {
                        defer {
                            debugPrint("All Saving done. - May be success or failure")
                        }
                        do {
                            try realm.write {
                                for realmObject in list {
                                    autoreleasepool{
                                        realm.add(realmObject, update: true)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch let error {
                            debugPrint(" Can't add Realm Object on thread \(Thread.current) thread and error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

let me know if anything is wrong in this.

Comment: What version of Realm is this

Comment: I dont understand? when the DB is empty it is small but after you save 50,000 records it gets big... That should be expected? or am I missing something?

Comment: I am using 3.1.0 version of Realm.